# events execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the execution order of two or more `change` events in jQuery?

```
$('#el').change(fn1);
$('#el').change(fn2);
$('#el').change(fn3);
```

I want to be sure that when I change the value of `el`, the `change` events will be executed in the exact order: `fn1`, `fn2`, `fn3`.

Comment: Yes, the callback functions will be executed in the order they are registered

Comment: Why do you need to bind multiple event handler? Surely it can be achieved using single event handler. Smells [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @tzortzik How about using a single change handler and inside that using `$.when` to execute the functions in specific order as you wish?

Comment: I do not want to use only one handler because I have attached one `change` handler for all the fields inside the page and I have another custom handler for only one field.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback functions will execute in the order they are registered:

```
  <input type="text" id="element">
```

In JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#element").change(function() {
    console.log("first"+this.value);
  });
   $("#element").change(function() {
    console.log("second"+this.value);
  });
   $("#element").change(function() {
    console.log("third"+this.value);
  });
});
```

As the value changes:

```
"first1"
"second1"
"third1"
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yowigi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Even better solution would be:

```
function fn1() {
 // do something
}
function fn2() {
 // do something
}
function fn3() {
 // do something
}
```

Inside your event handler:

```
$("#el").change(function() {
   $.when(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3).done(function(){
     // all done
   });
});
```